# Retornar uma variável em JavaScript e o conteúdo do PHP - AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Quero um script em `ajax` que na pagina me retorne o conteúdo para escrever em uma `div` e uma variável para usar no link da tag "A".

```
<a href=" escrever a variável aqui Y ">volta</a>
<br>
<div> escrever a conteudo aqui x </div>
```

No php coloquei bem básico

```
<?php
    $abrir = $_GET['dir'];

    //Y é a variavel que quero que escreva no link da tag A atualizando ele
    $Y =  $abrir . 'link_pasta/';

    //Conteudo que quero que escreva na div
    $X = '<p>conteúdo</p>';
?>
```

o script tem que ser acionado enviando variáveis, por exemplo: `<a href=index.php?dir=/pasta/">`

Comment: Precisa aprender Ajax primeiro (pesquise que tem muito material no site). Como você quer que retorne 2 valores distintos, teria que retornar um JSON.

Comment: Pode ser mais interessante procurar por **jQuery** do que por **javascript** para o tipo de pesquisa que está fazendo sozinho. Fora isso, ficaria mais simples para receber resposta de outras pessoas se explicar melhor o que quer. Em especial qual URL que será requisitada pelo AJAX, qual evento (clique? carregamento de página? etc) que puxa os dados da URL remota. E a dica do @sam de usar JSON tende a ser uma boa ideia fazer por padrão, mesmo se fosse apenas uma variável, pois é comum você mais tarde acabar precisando de outras informações (como dar uma resposta de erro se há falha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boas, existem n soluções. Veja um exemplo (necessita jQuery):

ficheiro html:

```html
<a href="#" id="lin">voltar</a>
<br>
<div id="divcont"></div>


<br><br>
<button id="teste">get</button>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $("#teste").click(
  function(){
   $.get( "meuphp.php?dir=exemplo", function( data ) {
     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
     $("#lin").attr("href",obj.link);
     $("#divcont").html(obj.div);
   });
  }
 );
 
</script>
```

ficheiro php:

```html
<?php
$abrir = $_GET['dir'];
$aux = array();
$aux['link'] =  $abrir . 'link_pasta/';
$aux['div'] = '<p>conteúdo</p>';
echo json_encode($aux);
?>
```